# slideUp / slideDown with string

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

Is there any way to do the slideUp() or slideDown() jquery function by using a string ?
For example :

```
$(".myDiv").do("slideUp");
```

Of course that code doesn't exist, but however it could be great to be able to write something like that :)
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic JS syntax for accessing object methods or properties is:

```
obj.property
obj.method()
// or
obj["property"]
obj["method"]()
```

The bit in the square brackets can be any JS expression that evaluates to be a string with the name of the property/method you want. So this what you are looking for:

```
$(".myDiv")["slideUp"]()
```

Which you can expand on with things like:

```
$(".myDiv")[someCondition ? "slideUp" : "slideDown"]()
// and
var method = "slideUp"
$(".myDiv")[method]()
```

Comment: Mister, you are my **hero of the day**, you just taught me something important in a very, very basic level. It works perfectly, so thank you very much :) (and damned, you were so fast !! Unfortunatelly, my clic can't vote up because I am too new on stackovertflow, but my heart did)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: nope, thank you, but the point is to write the smallest code as possible ^^
nnnnnn answer is perfect